# shell command to import a portion of mysql dump of a table (from a specific row)

Tags: mysql, shell, import, database-migration, data-consistency

Specifically:

is there a reverse command for this:

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME --where=<YOUR CLAUSE> > /path/to/output/file.sql
```

Can i import part of a table dump (from a specific row onwards) thru shell ?

Situation:
have a decent (2G) db **table** to import from PC to lynux mysql, i succeded to import approx 30% of that table using shell commands, then my connection to ISP went dead.

Problem:

i wish to continue uploading the dump **from the row where it stopped**. I specifically do not want to create a new dump from the row at wich the import stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of

```
sed -n $ROW,\$p file.sql
```

to your import command.